# Properties of the diff of a sorted uniformly generated set

Tags: normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, intuition, exponential-distribution, histogram

I am studying a set of uniformly generated points, more concretely the distance between the points.

When the set is unsorted the histrogram shows it is normally distributed and that matches my intuition:

```
hist(diff(runif(100,0,100)))
```

However, when the set is sorted the histogram resembles an exponential distribution:

```
hist(diff(sort(runif(100,0,100))))
```

The way my intuition works this  means that the most common distance between 2 consecutive endpoints is the smallest one of all the distances which seems odd to me, my intuition when looking at the problem was driving me more towards an inverse-gaussian, I understand the most common distances will be close to the bottom but I was not expecting it to be straight the smallest one.
What property of this system makes this happen?

Comment: Your questions concerns uniform spacings. A very good source on these is [Pyke (1965)](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1965.tb00602.x). The distribution of uniform spacings can be found therein. In your specific case, the density function is $f(D_{i})=100(1 - x/100)^{99}/100=(1-x/100)^{99}$.